# Should Actions Have Multiple Dispatches or Call Separately? ReactJs + Redux

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Say I have a button that "add" an item. An ajax request would be made if all goes well, the item would be added to the page and a success message would be shown.

there would be 2 dispatch events happening

```
Create
Notification
```

But what should be fireing of this events?

Say I have this method in my component that gets executed onClick

```
  validate() {
        if (this.state.storageName === "" && this.state.sharingKey == "") {
            console.log("validation error");
            return false;
        }

        this.props.createNewStorage(this.state);
        this.props.setNotifer(true);
    }
```

Right now CreateNewStorage looks like this

```
export function createNewStorage(storage) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.NEW_STORAGE_CREATED, payload: storage });
    };
}
```

setNotifer

```
export function setNotifer(success) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.SET_NOTIFIER, payload: success });
        setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: actions.CLOSE_NOTIFIER }), 1000);
    };
}
```

What I have right now(calling CreatenewStorage and setNotifier) would work but when I actually do an ajax request calling them like this won't work as CreateNewStorage might take awhile to return success while setNotifier would have already fired off.

So this leads me to where do I do multiple dispatches?

Way 1

```
export function createNewStorage(storage) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.NEW_STORAGE_CREATED, payload: storage });
dispatch({ type: actions.SET_NOTIFIER, payload: success });
        setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: actions.CLOSE_NOTIFIER }), 1000);
    };
```

Way 2

```
   export function createNewStorage(storage) {
        return function (dispatch) {
            dispatch({ type: actions.NEW_STORAGE_CREATED, payload: storage });
           setNotifer(true);
        };
    }
```

both of these ways of course would be wrapped around some sort of ajax method and would be put in success portion.

I just don't know if in way 2 it is ok to call another action method from one another.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to dispatch two events in the same call. You are using the thunk middleware it seems so it can be done easily but for those who aren't there is [Redux-Multi](https://github.com/ashaffer/redux-multi). That said, I would still prefer to dispatch them separately because:

1. Its easier to identify where the notification is emerging from for someone else who may work on your code.
2. You can programmatically control (delay, offset or pair with some other action etc) the notification if the call is made separately. You never know how you'll need to modify it. Yes, you may do at some place and not others but it would be better to stay consistent (point 1).

You can however make your `createNewStorage` *thenable* and dispatch the other event after its success (lets say you are doing some DB update and it fails so you don't want the user to see a success notification beforehand).

In your actions:

```
  export function createNewStorage(success) {
    return function (dispatch) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (somecondition === true) {
          dispatch({ type: actions.SET_NOTIFIER, payload: success });
          resolve('it works!');
        } else {
          reject(':(');
        }
      });
    };
  }
```

And in your component:

```
createNewStorage()
  .then(function() {
    ... launch the other action ...
  })
  .catch(function() {
    ... it failed :( ...
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I am using thunk middleware but I still new at all this and don't 100% know what it is. I been reading up on it. Could you provide some examples? Would not both ways I made make 2 dispatch calls?  They are pretty much the same thing but way 2 is calling another action.js file which has setNotifer(though I do realize now I have to wrap it in a dispatcher as doing it as I have in way 2 does nothing)

Comment: ah I am sorry I edited the question itself (new here)! so dumb :( Please look at my edited answer.

Comment: So is this thunk? I sort of see what your doing but not 100% sure. I would have though in create storage wrapped in the Promise would be an ajax request to create the storage then send out it's dispatch that the storage was created. Then in the components "then" would be the "SET_Notifer" call. Also it seems like the compoent "then" always gets called even if rejected?

Comment: Yes this works fine with thunk. Redux-Thunk only cares about that you pass in a function that receives a dispatch function as argument and not about what you do inside of that function. We are simply using a promise.

And no, _then_ is only called on success. See the edited code for fail scenario.